# Trying to rig a character but the rig won't work

Tags: modeling, rigging

I downloaded and textured this astronaut character, however, when I try to rig it, it just simply won't work. I generate a rig from the base human rig and parent it to my character, but the rig does nothing! I'm slowly losing my mind, but maybe someone here can help me out.

Link to my .blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19U_n66IlTGRf_epZ4V9YG4wZMPkGhF0K/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenting the rig to the character will not do anything except make your rig object follow your character object if moved arround.

If you want your character object to be deformed by your rig, you need to parent your character object to your rig with an armature deform.

To do this, select your model, then your armature, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open the `Set Parent To` menu, and any of the *Armature Deform*'s three sub-options :
[image]

Once it's done, depending the option you chose, your rig might already be able to move your character, but it's very rough, parts might be poorly assigned to bones, ... So you will probably have to edit this yourself.

If you chose Empty Groups or automatic weights (which I recommend for new users), you will have to go in weight paint mode and tweak.

There are a lot of tutorials and manuals about this process, so I invite you to find a nice one for you and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you! I used the Armature Deform with automatic weights, but now it returns an error, "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones". Do I have to prep my model in some way to be able to rig it properly?

Comment: Okay update: I figured it out! I just parented it with empty groups and started doing the weight paint myself. Thank you very much again for your quick response!

Comment: You're welcome!